# mysql how to select records where condition by age

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am using a query where i need to select the rows from users where age between (multiple ages)

like i have 3 users in table users with 3 fields :

ID   |  NAME  | DOB

1     |  A     | 12-06-1980
2     |  B     | 12-06-1970
3     |  C     | 12-06-1990
4     |  D     | 12-06-1995
5     |  E     | 12-06-1985

now if i want the list of users under 25 the out put

NAME  | DATE OF BIRTH

C     | 12-06-1990
D     | 12-06-1995

What the query whould be for this any idea ?

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE DOB
```

?
ANY IDEA

Comment: Check this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this ::

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DOB)/365<25
```

To get the age in years :

```
SELECT 
FLOOR(tempUsers.t/365) as `years`
tempUsers.t%365 as `months`
from
(
 SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DOB) t FROM users 
) tempUsers
```

Comment: what if i dont want to specify age 25 ? i want it to get age inside the query from date of birth column ?

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
from users
where DOB >= ADDDATE(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -25 YEAR);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE DOB >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 25 YEAR)
```

To calculate the 25 in above query from a `dateofbirth` date field, it would be as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE DOB >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),dateofbirth)/365) YEAR)
```

Comment: what if i dont want to specify age 25 ? i want it to get age inside the query from date of birth column ?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example of calculating the age ('25' in the previous example) from a `dateofbirth` field on the table.

Comment: @Nelson: Calculating the days difference in the where will not prompt return the age, you need to put the condition in the select clause.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this:

```
select id, name, dob,
  date_format(curdate(), '%Y') - date_format(dob, '%Y') - 
  (date_format(curdate(), '00-%m-%d') < date_format(dob, '00-%m-%d')) as age
from users
```

it is more precise than dividing by 365, eg. this gives 2001 which is wrong:

```
SELECT floor(DATEDIFF('4012-12-12', '2012-12-12')/365)
```

while this gives 2000 which is correct:

```
select
  date_format('4012-12-12', '%Y') - date_format('2012-12-12', '%Y') - 
  (date_format('4012-12-12', '00-%m-%d') < date_format('2012-12-12', '00-%m-%d'))
```

if you just have to calculate just an age, however, both solutions should work.